# Concatenate references and spaces in Do While loop VBA code issue

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to write a code to do the following - from sheet "Empl CP" combine data in columns E,F and G (representing Last, First and Middle name of employees) and write that combined field in sheet "Empl QC".
In between First, Last and Middle name must be spaces.

This code should repeat for each employee in sheet "Empl CP" (Do while loop used for this).

the code im using for this is following:

```
Sub CreateEmployees()

Dim counter As Integer
Dim cellCount As Integer

Dim Comb As String

Sheets("Empl CP").Activate

cellCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:A20000")) 'cell count counts number of Employee IDs
counter = 2 'Counter set on 2 to skip first header row of data


Do While counter <= (cellCount + 1) ' +1 because counter begins with 2 (ends 1 before cellCount)

Sheets("Empl CP").Activate

Comb = "='Empl CP'!E" & counter & "&'Empl CP'!F" & counter & "&'Empl CP'!G" & counter 'COMB filed containing Empl first, last and mid name

Sheets("Empl QC").Activate

Worksheets("Empl QC").Range("A" & counter) = Comb

counter = counter + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

In the code above, when creating "Comb" parameter, there are no spaces between First, Last and Middle names (so far the code is working properly). If I try to add space (after counter in "Comb =" line) by entering `"" "" &` ,I get an error requesting me to end statement. In case I use `" "" "" " &`, I get application run-time error 1004 (application-defined or object-defined error).

Can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Could you please edit the question or post a comment with the line including the additional spaces? 

`Comb = "='Empl CP'!E" & counter & "&'Empl CP'!F" & counter & "&'Empl CP'!G" & counter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you `Comb` expression should be written as follows:

```
Comb = "='Empl CP'!E" & counter & "&"" "" & 'Empl CP'!F" & counter & "&"" "" & 'Empl CP'!G" & counter
```

but you'd better avoid `Activate` and go with fully qualified range references

and `Join()` function could be helpful here

as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateEmployees()
    Dim iDatum As Long

    With Sheets("Empl CP")
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
            ReDim data(1 To .count) As String
            For iDatum = 1 To .count
                data(iDatum) = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Offset(iDatum - 1, 4).Resize(1, 3).Value)))
            Next
        End With
        Worksheets("Empl QC").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(data)).Value = Application.Transpose(data)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my issue. I appreciate it :)